Show ErrorView and Then Hide it in 2 Seconds
I am working on creating an ErrorView that can be displayed from anywhere (not modals) in a SwiftUI app.
The problem is to reset the ErrorView after 2 seconds. I have code that fires and sets the errorWrapper to nil but what if the user clicks on the button twice. The reset will never finish.
struct ContentViewContainer: View {
    @State private var errorWrapper: ErrorWrapper?
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.showError, ShowErrorAction(action: showError))
           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.green)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                errorWrapper != nil ? ErrorView(errorWrapper: $errorWrapper) : nil
            })
}

Here is my ErrorView:
struct ErrorView: View {
    @State private var hidden: Bool = false
    @Binding var errorWrapper: ErrorWrapper?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(errorWrapper?.error.localizedDescription ?? "")
            Text(errorWrapper?.guidance ?? "")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                withAnimation {
                    hidden = true
                    errorWrapper = nil // THIS WILL NOT GET CALLED WHEN THE USER TAPS MULTIPLE TIMES BUTTON
                }
            }
            
        })
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .padding()
        .background(.red)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0, style: .continuous))
        .opacity(hidden ? 0: 1)
    }
}

And here is ContentView that sets the errorWrapper:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.showError) private var showError
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Throw Error") {
                showError(SampleError.operationFailed, "Operation has failed.")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


This code can't be run. It needs a [mre]. As a general concept, though, you should use task with await to close the modal.

This is a good candidate for using task(id:), which will fire whenever the id changes and can be cancelled.
You'll want your ErrorWrapper, which you haven't shown, so I couldn't edit it, to be Identifiable. You'll probably just have to add an id to whatever you currently have.
struct IdentifiableError: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var message: String
}

struct ContentViewContainer: View {
    
    @State private var errorWrapper: IdentifiableError?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ContentView(showError: { errorWrapper = $0 })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.green)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                errorWrapper != nil ? ErrorView(errorWrapper: $errorWrapper) : nil
            }
    }
}

struct ErrorView: View {
    @Binding var errorWrapper: IdentifiableError?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(errorWrapper?.message ?? "")
        }
        .task(id: errorWrapper?.id) {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
            guard !Task.isCancelled else { return }
            errorWrapper = nil
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .padding()
        .background(.red)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0, style: .continuous))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var showError: (IdentifiableError) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Throw Error") {
                showError(.init(id: UUID(), message: "Operation has failed."))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

